# How to change the color of multiple freqz plots?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I am plotting multiple frequency responses on the same plot using "hold" and "freqz" in MATLAB. Is there any way to adjust the color of each plot so I can identify which one is which? Right now it looks like a mess.

[image]

Freqz doesn't appear to support changing the plot's color like "plot" does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's indeed a little tricky as `freqz` does not provide a handle.

```
b = fir1(80,0.5,kaiser(81,8));
freqz(b,1); hold on
c = fir1(80,0.9,kaiser(81,8));
freqz(c,1); hold on
```

But you can get them by using `findall`:

```
lines = findall(gcf,'type','line');
```

and then color the lines as usual:

```
lines(1).Color = 'red'
lines(2).Color = 'green'
lines(3).Color = 'red'
lines(4).Color = 'green'
```

or for Matlab versions prior to 2014b:

```
set(lines(1),'Color','red')
set(lines(2),'Color','green')
set(lines(3),'Color','red')
set(lines(4),'Color','green')
```

It works for all [**`LineSpec` properties**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html).

[image]

Comment: @codedude yes! It works for all [**`LineSpec` properties**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linespec.html)

Comment: Tks great solution. Just a quirk, had to use .Color instead of .color. (not sure if it's a version thing, I'm using 2017b). Also, the phase plot gets replaced, not added (so I only end up with the last phase plot). This last issue is confirmed by length of lines being 3 instead of 4...